# Is there a way to create an event handler code in another class and just call it

Tags: c#

I want create a small project in M V C pattern and I want to separate my code into three parts.

I used Model in one part and view Controller in another but now I want to separate controller as well.

this is from event now i want to use this in controller and just call it here:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string query = "Select * from [UserTbl] where username='" + txtusername.Text + "' and password='" + txtpassword.Text + "'";
                DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
                DataTable dt = db.GetData(query);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username and Password Incorrect");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

this is control class

```
 public class LoginControl
    {


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In its simplest, most literal form,

```
public class Authentication
{
    public void Login(string userName, string password)
    {
            try
            {
                string query = "Select * from [UserTbl] where username='" + userName + "' and password='" + password + "'";
                DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
                DataTable dt = db.GetData(query);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username and Password Incorrect");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
    }
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var authentication = new Authentication();
    authentication.Login(txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);
}
```

I'm sidestepping the fact that this doesn't seem to do anything other than display a result. Presumably you're doing something else not seen in this code. Also, creating SQL by concatenating the user ID and password creates a serious SQL injection risk, so you should use parameters instead.

This might be sufficient if the method is absolutely only intended to be used in the context of this single application. But what if you want this to be usable in some context where `MessageBox.Show` isn't available? Maybe you want to be able to reuse this login code outside of any Windows Forms app. (It's good if we can minimize the amount of our code that is tied to any UI.)

You can separate that by having your method return a result. That way the method indicates whether something was successful, and your UI code determines if or how to communicate that to a user. In that case your method could look more like this:

```
public bool Login(string userName, string password)
{
    string query = "Select * from [UserTbl] where username='" + userName + "' and password='" + password + "'";
    DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
    DataTable dt = db.GetData(query);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    // or, just
    // return dt.Rows.Count > 0;
}
```

In many cases it would make sense to return some sort of `Result` class with more detail, but for this example, a `bool` representing success of failure is enough.

Now your UI code can do this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var authentication = new Authentication();
        var success = authentication.Login(txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);
        if (success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password Incorrect");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If you needed to reuse the above code and didn't want to duplicate it you could create a separate control, moving both the button and the click handler into it.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm assuming this is WinForms?**

You could add a public function to `LoginControl` and just call it from the `button1_Click` event handler.

You won't have access to the form's controls within `LoginControl`, so you'll have to pass the values you need from the form's controls  to the function you write. Your function could return something to indicate whether the login was successful or not, that way you can show the correct message from the `button1_Click` event handler.